# Find files starting with a specific characters using regex

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to exclude files starting with characters `~$` from archiving using the regex.

Example of directory contains files:

- `~$file01.txt`
- `~$file02.txt`
- `file01.txt`
- `file02.txt`

So, I want find all the files in dir that start with "~$", and I've tried the following regex but files are still not excluded

```
.*/~[^/]*
```

What's wrong with this?

It is software that archiving files.
I want to exclude from archiving the filenames starting with ~$.
All files will be archived, only files starting with ~$ will not be.
In this software, there is option to add regular expression to exclude files from archiving.
[regular-expressions.info](https://regular-expressions.info) link is part of the software documentation, but I don't know how to write the needed regular expression.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly are you using the regular expression to match the file names? Show the command(s) or code you are using, the actual result/output you get and the expected output.

Comment: If you want file beginning with `~$`, why is the second character set to be anything other than `/`. Can you try `echo ./~\$*`?

Comment: I assume you mean _filenames_, not file contents. But what you using that regex with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,
As mentioned in the comments it would've been better if you provided more detail, especially on the exact command you're using to achieve this, however, since it's regex-related I think the following would be helpful:

Consider these syntaxes:

```bash
(?=subexp)         look-ahead
(?!subexp)         negative look-ahead
(?<=subexp)        look-behind
(?<!subexp)        negative look-behind
```

So in your case it'd be:

```bash
(?<!~\$).*
```

Comment: Related to more detail, it is software and there is only a text field in which I can enter a regex to exclude necessary files.
(?<!~$).* don't work either :(

Comment: Well, it's actually understandable that it wouldn't work since I've only used this in the shell specifically `zsh`.
Could you share the software's name so I'd research a little?
If sharing the software's not possible I would totally understand.

Comment: ALSO, please try this too `(?<!~\$).*`

Comment: This ^~\$.* works great.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I will update my answer then, you're welcome.